# How to parse this type of JSON using C# JsonConvert?

Tags: c#, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse a JSON response which looks like this:

```
{
    "users" : [{id: 1, ...},{id: 2, ...}],
    "count": 200
}
```

into List of Users using C#. I've tried parsing it this way:

```
Dictionary<string, List<User>> parsedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<User>>>(result);
```

but got an error indicating that (count:100) can not be parsed.
Now I am able to get the result using

```
Dictionary<string, dynamic> parsedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(result);
```

but I want to be sure that parsedJson["users"] is going to be a List of User. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Create a class that contains a `List<User> Users` and an `int Count`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON response is an object with two properties, so you should try:

```
public class JsonResponseDto
{
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
    public int Count {get; set; }
}

var deserializedResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResponseDto>(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any extra class

```
List<User> users = JObject.Parse(result)["users"].ToObject<List<User>>();
```

and if you need count

```
int count = users.Count;
```